# Bad quality video DVB-T MPEG4 after a few minutes

Tags: ffmpeg, mythtv

I have a problem with mythfrontend in Oneiric installed from Mythbuntu. I cannot watch TV after few minutes because of lots of artifacts. I have a Hauppauge 1300 DVB-T tuner and MPEG-4 compression is used. Signal is OK because I can watch in VLC wihtout problems. There are in logs many entries like:

```
2012-02-16 20:20:10.693 [h264 @ 0x4430bb40]Missing reference picture
2012-02-16 20:20:10.704 [h264 @ 0x4430bb40]mmco: unref short failure
2012-02-16 20:20:10.704 [h264 @ 0x4430bb40]mmco: unref short failure
2012-02-16 20:20:10.704 [h264 @ 0x4430bb40]illegal short term buffer state detected
2012-02-16 20:20:10.796 [h264 @ 0x4430bb40]illegal short term buffer state detected
```

It can be a ffmpeg issue but how to install current/updated ffmpeg that will meet mythbuntu dependencies?

Comment: Probably better suited to the [Mythbuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/forumdisplay.php?f=301) where people can narrow down the problem over the course of some time/posts. This doesn't look like something we'll be able to work out from the information posted, and we could be back and forth for quite some time..

Answer (score 0):

i don't know man any problem in codec is very hard to solve it

but you can download and play umplayer this software very good as good player and download useful codecs mpeg , realplayer and others

http://www.umplayer.com/

so download it , install and see what will happened my bay fix this problem

and something other try to change settings specials video code in your program may be solve this problem

i've satellite card and have problem when i play it in windows with program like dvbdream

and solve when change another settings video codec in this program

Answer (score 0):

use this link fix ffmpeg

http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=chromium-codecs-ffmpeg

http://packages.ubuntu.com/chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra